# Is it possible to set the equivalent of a src attribute to the first img src of a page in html and javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am probably missing something simple but it's quite annoying when everything you read doesn't work. 
I am trying to set the "throbber" img src to the first img src of a webpage. So far, I've got:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
           var image = document.createElement("img");
var imageParent = document.getElementById("body");
image.id = "id";
image.className = "class";
image.src = searchPic.src;            // image.src = "IMAGE URL/PATH"
imageParent.appendChild(image);
```

Would it be possible to implement this with html only?
            
And

```
<div id="throbber"><img src="http://www.cloudaccess.net/images/Google-Chrome-Extensions.jpg" /></div>
```

Is it possible to change the img src to the first img src of a page depending on the website?

Comment: What do you mean by "dependign on the website"?

Comment: If I wanted to append the first child image of a website, how would I implement that with html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your throbber image is in the website from which you're trying to pull the image, you can use jquery like this:

```
$(function (){
    // get the src of the first image that is not your throbber image
    var src = $('img:not("#throbber img")').attr('src');
    // set the throbber image to this src
    $('#throbber img').attr('src', src);
});
```

Comment: When I run this, it returns the throbber image. I'm hoping for it to return a dynamic image. Am I missing something?https://jsfiddle.net/97xo4ddk/

Comment: I tried this alert($(this).find('img'). attr('src'); as well.

Comment: The fiddle you showed was not using my code it was using leo.fcx's. Look at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dppvjowx/2/. The code finds the first img tag that is not inside a div with and ID of 'throbber' and sets the throbber image to the src.

Comment: Thank you. Is there anyway to not type in the url of the image src manually? rather, have manipulate the code to find the first image on a webpage'

Comment: If the page you are trying to pull the image from is on the same domain as the one you're throbber image is displayed in then 'Yes'. However if you're trying to pull the image from a website that is not in the same domain then NO. You could use an ajax call to pull the html of a website and search it for the first <img> tag but if the page you are calling is not on your domain it would be considered cross site scripting and would be blocked unless the page you are pulling from has header settings that allow it. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes, I was just hoping I could return document.images[0].src;  instead of a set url. if anyone knows how to do this with js , jquery, html and css, please let me know.

Comment: Like this <img src="getImgSrc" id="imgClickAndChange" data-images="clear,full,arbitrary,other,images" />. however, the function getImgSrc isn't read.

Comment: I'm still not certain what you're really trying to do. You could use document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src to get the source of the first img tag. The confusing part for me is what you mean when you say 'depending on the website'. Are you trying to inject this throbber image into a site over which you have no control?

Comment: yes, i'm building a chrome extension. however, i don't want to inject an image, i want to store the first image of the website  a user is on (whether locally or not) and then show it in the popup through html and js if possible.

Comment: OK, I've never built a chrome extension. but if you have access to the document being loaded. And you can set variables, you should be able to get the src of the first image by using var throbber = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src;

Comment: Thank you for your time Gregg. I'm sorry if I wasn't clear at first. I'm just now realizing that coding chrome extensions do NOT equal coding with websites. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is. Try following code:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var divEl = document.getElementById('throbber');
    var image = divEl.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];

    // set the new image
    image.src= 'https://your/new/image.png';

}
```

Note that we need to take advantage of `window.onload` in order to make sure `DOM` is ready before manipulating it.

See this **[JSfiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/97xo4ddk/)**

Comment: I edited my original post to be more clear. Sorry I am new to this...instead of using one definitive url for image.src, how can I change that in html to change with the open tab?

Comment: For instance, in JSfiddle, it might display the jsfiddle logo, but on stackoverflow, it would display this logo. Does that make any sense?